# Copy images and create collection and apply drag and drop android app

Tags: android, drag, paste

I want to create android app like cake maker game. I want to copy few images from grid view and paste that images into another folder ( when I click on image in the grid view it should automatically appear on one folder) like this way I want to take few images from grid view into one folder and after collecting all required images into one folder I want to apply drag and drop facilities on that images.
Need guidance to create such app.

Comment: try this http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidDragAndDrop/article.html

Comment: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_drag_and_drop.htm